# How to prove a disk is not open?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

**Question:** Suppose I have the set $D = \{(x,y,0) |x^{2}+y^{2} <1 \} \subset \mathbb{R}^{3}$. Prove that this is not an open set in the metric space defined by ($\mathbb{R}^{3}$,Euclidean metric).

**My Attempt:** I understand this is not open in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ because its simply a open disk in the $xy$-plane with $z=0$. I also know the definition of not open is $\exists a \in D \quad \textrm{such that} \quad \forall \epsilon>0 , V _\epsilon (a) \nsubseteq D  $. I also know the neighborhood definition. Here's my proof's skeleton so far,

Let $a \in D$ be $a=$

Suppose $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary.

Let $b\in V_\epsilon(a)$ and let $b=$

So, $b \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$ and $d(a,b)< \epsilon$ by the definition of neighborhood

I don't know what $a$ and $b$ should be and I don't know how to connect that to show $b\notin D $.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $a = (0,0,0)$, and $b = (0,0,\epsilon/2)$. Then $b$ is in the $\epsilon$-ball centered at $a$ but not in the disk.

Comment: I understand that but how do I formally write that?

Comment: @ChemDude What do you mean? This is formal enough. If you want fancy symbols to justify the claim: we have that $d(a,b) = \epsilon/2 < \epsilon$, so $b \in V_\epsilon(a)$, but $b \not\in D$ because its last coordinate is not zero. Readability and conciseness are generally preferred to fancy symbolism, though. (In this scenario, your putative reader is probably able to see why $d(a,b) < \epsilon$ instantly without you doing the computation in his stead.)

Comment: Ok I was thinking there was some "formal" way to write it but this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

A set is open if, for any point in that set, you can put an open ball of sufficiently small radius. Visualising what's going on here, it's clear that any ball with positive radius will escape the disc $D$. Does this give you an idea of how to formalise the proof? If I put a ball at $(x, y, 0)$ of radius $r>0$, can you write down coordinates for a point inside the ball that is not in $D$?

Comment: This actually proves something strictly stronger: that the interior of $D$ is empty.  If all you want is to prove that $D$ is not open, then you only need to find one counterexample of a point of $D$ such that no open ball around that point is contained in $D$.